# Jenkins crash after I restart it

Tags: linux, jenkins

Hi All I have a very old Jenkins version 1.646 I just install pipeline-utility-steps-plugin and restart jenkins and now when jenkins start it just said **Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work** then it shows a white page.

how can I fix it? i just manually remove that plug in form the plugins folder

here is the log file https://www.mediafire.com/file/w6zlw7wv8rwcddb/jenkins.log/file

[image: Jenkins image]

[image: Jenkins image]

Comment: Did you take a look at Jenkins logs?

Comment: Hi Tupteq yes but i don't understand it since is too long let me add the log

Comment: here is the jenkins log file https://file.io/FcMGiW and thanks for your help

Comment: Can't see the file - error 404.

Comment: please try with this one https://www.mediafire.com/file/w6zlw7wv8rwcddb/jenkins.log/file

Comment: also this log is shorter because i remove the old one and i can see multiple times at the end of the log this error: Error when retrieving ScmSyncConfig plugin instance => No filtering enabled on current request

Comment: Does it answer to your question: [JENKINS-33733](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33733)?

Comment: The scmsyncplugin is not really robust and I would suggest to stop using it. Had many issues with that one.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use ScmSyncConfigPlugin, there are other ways to backup your config and this plugin has design issues anyway which put your jenkins instance stability at risk.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the plugin manually by logging into the server and you can start the Jenkins Service. Make sure about reviews and compatibility of plugins to respective versions in case of trying new ones.